# Regla de tres para generar series en un dataframe a traves de python - colab

Tags: python, dataframe

Hola tengo el siguiente problema al momento de poder rellenar la siguiente información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me gustaría rellenar la información primero distribuyendo el costo total de acuerdo a las unidades producidas por categoría por mes y año y luego con este costo por categoría poder distribuir en función de la proporción del costo totales directo e indirecto por mes y año los costos directos e indirectos por categoría por mes y año

Para ello use el siguiente código pero no me esta arrojando los resultados esperados, creando dos archivos uno solo de costos totales por mes y año y otro con las cantidades producidas por mes:

```
import pandas as pd

# Cargar los datos de los archivos CSV
df_costos = pd.read_csv('costos.csv')
df_cantidades = pd.read_csv('cantidades.csv')

# Calcular los costos totales por categoría, mes y año
df_costos_categorias = pd.merge(df_cantidades, df_costos, on=['Año', 'Mes'])
df_costos_categorias['Costo total por categoría'] = df_costos_categorias['Costo total'] * df_costos_categorias['Unidades producidas'] / df_costos_categorias.groupby(['Año', 'Mes', 'Categoría'])['Unidades producidas'].transform('sum')

# Calcular los costos directos por categoría, mes y año
df_costos_categorias['Costo directo por categoría'] = df_costos_categorias['Costo directo'] * df_costos_categorias['Unidades producidas'] / df_costos_categorias.groupby(['Año', 'Mes', 'Categoría'])['Unidades producidas'].transform('sum')

# Calcular los costos indirectos por categoría, mes y año
df_costos_categorias['Costo indirecto por categoría'] = df_costos_categorias['Costo indirecto'] * df_costos_categorias['Unidades producidas'] / df_costos_categorias.groupby(['Año', 'Mes', 'Categoría'])['Unidades producidas'].transform('sum')

# Mostrar los resultados
print(df_costos_categorias)
```

Comment: Cuando dices *no me esta arrojando los resultados esperados*, no especificas cuál es el problema, tal vez si agregas algún o algunos ejemplos de los resultados esperados tu pregunta estaría más clara. ;)

Comment: En este código no se generan archivos, sólo se leen dos y se manipulan unos dataframes.